# How to style DraftJS editor in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, draftjs

I am implementing a web ui with React and the [Material UI library](https://material-ui.com/).

I need a custom styled DraftJS editor component but none of my tries worked.

Let's imagine I want to have a red color for my hole text block within my editor component.

The Editor Component got child `<div class="DraftEditor-root">` which I want to style through my Editor component.

For that I tried the `className`:

```
const styles = () => ({
    myEditorStyle: {
        "& root": {
            color: "red"
         }
    }
})


render() {
const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
        <Editor className={classes.myEditorStyle}/>
    )
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MaterialTextEditor);
```

and `classes`:

```
const styles = {
    myEditorStyle: {
        color: "red"
    }
}


render() {
const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
        <Editor classes={{ root={classes.myEditorStyle} }}
    )
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MaterialTextEditor);
```

But that does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `className` if you want to assign a class instead of `classname`

Comment: Sorry, a mistake in my code snippet. I always use "className".